# PHP Умножение модуля чисел, при этом не изменяя код класса

Tags: php

Есть класс, который умножает 2 числа. Как сделать так, чтоб он умножал модули чисел, при этом не изменяя код класса, интерфейса и строки с выводом результата. Т.е. вызов echo $multiplier->multiply(2, -5); должен вывести 10.

```
// Не менять
interface MultiplierInterface
{
    // Не менять
    public function multiply($x, $y);
}

// Не менять
final class Multiplier implements MultiplierInterface
{
    // Не менять
    public function multiply($x, $y)
    {
        return $x * $y;
    }
}

$multiplier = new Multiplier();

// Не менять
echo $multiplier->multiply(2, -5);

// должен быть вывод 10
```

Comment: $multiplier->multiply(2, abs(-5));

Comment: @JurijJazdanov тогда уж `abs($multiplier->multiply(2, -5));` но скорее всего тут дело в паттернах или одном из аспектах ООП

Comment: Не один из вариантов не подходит..

Comment: на основе чего сделан такой вывод? и к чему он должен подходить? пока твой вопрос абсолютно не ясен. что у тебя есть и что ты хочешь получить

Comment: Может переформулируете свой вопрос, что бы было понятно что именно требуется ?

Вот пример решения:
class Multiplier {
    public function multiply($a, $b) {
        return $a * $b;
    }
}

$multiplier = new Multiplier();

class ModifiedMultiply extends Multiplier {
    public function multiply($a, $b) {
        return abs(parent::multiply($a, $b));
    }
}

$multiplier = new ModifiedMultiply();

echo $multiplier->multiply(2, -5);

Строку вывода мы не трогаем, но создаем другой класс и унаследуем тот что имеется, вызываем родительский метод multiply и применяем abs

Comment: Дополнил вопрос..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-redefine.php

Comment: Ну собственно то что предложил не противоречит тому примеру что у вас есть. Вы можете создать свой класс, унаследовать Multiplier и переопределить метод, в котором вызвать родительский метод, и результат изменить как вам удобно. Строку с выводом менять не надо если переменную переопределить ранее

Comment: @walik только класс-то `final`. Скорее rjhdby прав, хоть это и ужасы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ужас я в ответе написал :)

Comment: @rjhdby я могу другой ужас показать))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну давайте еще ужасами померяемся! :D Однако ответ подошел... гхм...

Comment: @rjhdby я через "декоратор" вроде сделал)

Comment: Менять передаваемые параметры нельзя, а долбить буфер в норме вещей, что за бред?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function callback($buffer){
    return (str_replace("-", "", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");

тут ваш код

ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

for fun:

```
// Не менять
interface MultiplierInterface {
    // Не менять
    public function multiply($x, $y);
}

// Не менять
final class Multiplier implements MultiplierInterface {
    // Не менять
    public function multiply($x, $y) {
        return $x * $y;
    }
}

final class MultiplyABS implements MultiplierInterface {
    private $multiplier = null;

    public function __construct(Multiplier $multiplier) {
        $this->multiplier = $multiplier;
    }

    public function multiply($x, $y) {
        return abs($this->multiplier->multiply($x, $y));
    }
}

$multiplier =  new MultiplyABS(new Multiplier());

// Не менять
echo $multiplier->multiply(2, -5);
```

Это называется шаблон проектирования "декоратор"